# paint.net enter exact coordinates

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, paint.net

when using paint.net, to say draw a line, is there any way to enter precise coordinates using the keyboard?

I am thinking of what you can do in sketchup to draw exact lines by entering lengths.

Comment: I would check the documentation for Paint.net.  If its not there I would ask on the Paint.net forum.  Its very likely Paint.net doesn't have this feature out of the box.

Comment: @GreyCloud - did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Tama, no, unfortunately not :-/